# Adding component inside of div in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I am using [this Vue module](https://github.com/kirillmurashov/vue-drag-resize#events) for draggable and resizable objects. I want to create draggable-resizable boxes that include dropdown menus, input fields, and radio buttons. For now, I only added a `<select>` tag for simplicity.

My problem is, even though I specifically placed `<VueDragResize>` inside `<div id="canvas">`, the draggable-resizable box appears outside of the div, on the top-left corner of the viewport. This behavior remained even when I added `:parentLimitation="true"`.

Secondly, I am not able to select and change the dropdown menu. I tried adding a custom onActivated function to the select tag but still doesn't let me select and change the dropdown:

```
<select name="cars" id="cars" ref="dropdown-cars" v-on:activated="onActivated">
...
onActivated() {
   this.$refs['dropdown-cars'].focus();
}
```

My full code in App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="canvas">
      <VueDragResize :isActive="true" :w="200" :h="200" v-on:resizing="resize" v-on:dragging="resize" :parentLimitation="true">
          <h3>Drag and Resize Me!</h3>
          <select name="cars" id="cars" ref="dropdown-cars" v-on:activated="onActivated">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          </select>
      </VueDragResize>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script> 

  import VueDragResize from 'vue-drag-resize'

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      VueDragResize,
    },

    methods: {
      resize(newRect) {
        this.width = newRect.width;
        this.height = newRect.height;
        this.top = newRect.top;
        this.left = newRect.left;
      },
      onActivated() {
        this.$refs['dropdown-cars'].focus();
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
#canvas {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vw;
  background-color: #2f3f50;
  border: 20px  black;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `position: relative;` to `#canvas`. The `VueDragResize` component is placed based on CSS position (it seems) - if there's no `relative`, `absolute`, `fixed` in its "ancestor path", then the `body` is the only thing it can be positioned against
2. The `@activated` (`v-on:activated`) is an event of `VueDragResize`, so the handler should be placed on that component.
3. I suggest adding `@clicked`, otherwise it's going to be hard to get the form fields active.

I see that the form fields (`select` in this snippet) do not receive the click event -> you can only use them with keyboard commands (e.g. `tab`, `arrow down`, etc.). Not good UX - but if you accept this hindrance, then it works.

```js
const VueDragResize = window.VueDragResize.default

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    VueDragResize,
  },
  methods: {
    resize(newRect) {
      this.width = newRect.width;
      this.height = newRect.height;
      this.top = newRect.top;
      this.left = newRect.left;
    },
    onActivated(e) {
      this.$refs['dropdown-cars'].focus();
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <div id="canvas">
        <VueDragResize
          :isActive="true"
          :parentLimitation="true"
          :w="200"
          :h="200"
          @resizing="resize"
          @dragging="resize"
          @activated="onActivated"
          @clicked="onActivated"
        >
          <h3>Drag and Resize Me!</h3>
            <select
              name="cars"
              id="cars"
              ref="dropdown-cars"
            >
              <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
              <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            </select>
            <select
              name="cars2"
              id="cars2"
              ref="dropdown-cars2"
            >
              <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
              <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            </select>
        </VueDragResize>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
```

```css
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

#canvas {
  position: relative;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vw;
  background-color: #2f3f50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-drag-resize@1/dist/index.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```